# playstore reject apps with no library armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 but no x86-64 and no (.so) files?

Tags: android, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I created a sample app with android studio using only mediaplayer and images and implementation from Google.

After building the app I checked it with the Analyze tool in android studio to see if there is a lib folder and (.so) files as it says in Support 64-bit architectures documentation but there is nothing which means the app support 64 bit.

I tested the app in 64 bit phone worked perfectly the same thing in 32 bit but when I upload to google play they say (this release is not compliant with the google play 64-bit requirement).

I tried the (`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'` method and the same thing happened no change can anyone explain to me how to fix this or check you google play console.

> Build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.preschoollearning.game"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 18
        versionName "2.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int id;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    GridLayout mainGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("........");

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (finalI == 0)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlphabetActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }
                    else if (finalI == 1)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumberActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }
                    else if  (finalI == 2)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ColorActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }
                    else if  (finalI == 3)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShapesActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }
                    else if  (finalI == 4)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnimalsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }
                    else if  (finalI == 5)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BirdsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }
                    else if  (finalI == 6)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FlagsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }
                    else if  (finalI == 7)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,VehicalsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        stopAudio();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        displayInterstitial();
        finish();

    }


    //Play Audio
    private void playAudio(int paramInt) {
        this.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, paramInt);
        this.mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        this.mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    //Stop Audio
    private void stopAudio() {
        try {
            if (this.mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    this.mediaPlayer.stop();
                this.mediaPlayer.release();
                this.mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception localException) {
            while (true)
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + localException);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        stopAudio();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        stopAudio();
    }
}
```

> OtherActivity and it's same in the other Activity

```
public class AnimalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView imgAnimals;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int position;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    ImageButton btn_voice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animals);
        playAudio(Constants.ANIMALS_SOUND[position]);

        btn_voice = findViewById(R.id.btn_voice);
        btn_voice.setOnClickListener(this);


        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("....");

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        imgAnimals = findViewById(R.id.imgAnimals);


        imgAnimals.setImageResource(Constants.ANIMALS_IMAGES[position]);

        imgAnimals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Play word audio when tap in Word Images
                playAudio(Constants.ANIMALS_SOUND[position]);
            }
        });


        Button btnPrevious = findViewById(R.id.btnPrev3);
        Button btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNex3);
        Button play = findViewById(R.id.play);

        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position > 0) {
                    updateActivity(position - 1);
                    position = position - 1;
                } else {
                    updateActivity((Constants.ANIMALS_IMAGES.length - 1));
                    position = Constants.ANIMALS_IMAGES.length - 1;
                }
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position < (Constants.ANIMALS_IMAGES.length - 1)) {
                    updateActivity(position + 1);
                    position = position + 1;
                } else {
                    updateActivity(0);
                    position = 0;
                }
            }
        });


        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                playAudio(Constants.ANIMALS_SOUND[position]);
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        displayInterstitial();
        finish();

    }


    private void updateActivity(final int position) {
        imgAnimals.setImageResource(Constants.ANIMALS_IMAGES[position]);
        playAudio(Constants.ANIMALS_SOUND[position]);

        imgAnimals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Play word audio when tap in Word Images
                playAudio(Constants.ANIMALS_SOUND[position]);
            }
        });
    }

    // Play audio
    private void playAudio(int paramInt) {
        stopAudio();
        if (this.mediaPlayer != null)
            this.mediaPlayer.reset();
        this.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, paramInt);
        this.mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        this.mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    // Stop audio
    private void stopAudio() {
        try {
            if (this.mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (this.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    this.mediaPlayer.stop();
                this.mediaPlayer.release();
                this.mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception localException) {
            while (true)
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + localException);
        }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_voice){

            Intent intent = new Intent(AnimalsActivity.this,AnimalVoiceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", 1);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            stopAudio();
        }
    }
}
```

> Constant

```
public class Constants {


    static final int[] ALPHABET_IMAGES = { R.drawable.alphabet_1, R.drawable.alphabet_2,
            R.drawable.alphabet_3, R.drawable.alphabet_4, R.drawable.alphabet_5, R.drawable.alphabet_6,
            R.drawable.alphabet_7, R.drawable.alphabet_8, R.drawable.alphabet_9, R.drawable.alphabet_10,
            R.drawable.alphabet_11, R.drawable.alphabet_12, R.drawable.alphabet_13, R.drawable.alphabet_14,
            R.drawable.alphabet_15, R.drawable.alphabet_16, R.drawable.alphabet_17, R.drawable.alphabet_18,
            R.drawable.alphabet_19, R.drawable.alphabet_20, R.drawable.alphabet_21, R.drawable.alphabet_22,
            R.drawable.alphabet_23, R.drawable.alphabet_24, R.drawable.alphabet_25, R.drawable.alphabet_26};


    static final int[] APHABET_SOUND = { R.raw.alphabet_1, R.raw.alphabet_2,
            R.raw.alphabet_3, R.raw.alphabet_4, R.raw.alphabet_5, R.raw.alphabet_6,
            R.raw.alphabet_7, R.raw.alphabet_8, R.raw.alphabet_9, R.raw.alphabet_10,
            R.raw.alphabet_11, R.raw.alphabet_12, R.raw.alphabet_13, R.raw.alphabet_14,
            R.raw.alphabet_15, R.raw.alphabet_16, R.raw.alphabet_17, R.raw.alphabet_18,
            R.raw.alphabet_19, R.raw.alphabet_20, R.raw.alphabet_21, R.raw.alphabet_22,
            R.raw.alphabet_23, R.raw.alphabet_24, R.raw.alphabet_25, R.raw.alphabet_26 };
}
```

> AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AnimalsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[Apk Analyze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZaLs.png)

Comment: Is there any C/C++ code? Can we see your build.gradle as well?

Comment: i add the build code and the MainActivity and the OtherActivity

Comment: try building and uploading app-bundle instead of the .apk file

Comment: I did the app-bundle the same thing happened no change same messege

Comment: Try unzipping the APK. Replace .apk in the filename with .zip and see if there is a lib folder. Additionally, can we see AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i add the apk analyze picture and manifest and there is no lib files as you can see in the apk analyze image